# How to detect if a string input has more than one consecutive space?

Tags: java, string, input, char, space

For a class I have to make a morse code program using a binary tree. The user is suppose to enter morse code and the program will decode it and print out the result. The binary tree only holds A-Z. And I only need to read   dashes, dots, and spaces. If there is one space that is the end of the letter. If there is 2 or more spaces in a row that is the end of the word.

How do you detect if the string input has consecutive spaces? Right now I have it programmed where it detects if there is 2 (which will then print out a space), but i dont know how to have it where it knows there is 3+ spaces.

This is how I'm reading the input btw:

```
String input =  showInputDialog( "Enter Code", null);
character = input.charAt(i);
```

And this is how I have it detecting a space:    `if (character == ' ')`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you can detect 2 spaces, you're 2/3 of the way to detecting 3 spaces.

Comment: Show us more code.  How are you currently detecting 2 spaces?

Comment: Use a `int spaceCount = 0`.  Increase it if and only if the next letter is a space, otherwise count back to 0.  Best way I can think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this which if you had more than one item in the resulting array would tell you that you had at least one instance of 2+ spaces.

```
    String[] foo = "a b  c   d".split("  +");
```

This splits into "a b", "c", and "d".

You'd probably need regex checks than just that though if you need to detect how many of each count of spaces (e.g. how many 2 spaces, how many 3 spaces, etc).

Comment: This should be simple enough that the OP shouldn't need regex at all.  Given the assignment, I'd guess that regex is probably a little more advanced than he's really looking for.

Comment: I don't really think of regex as advanced. Cryptic certainly :), but sort of a standard part of the parsing toolkit.

Comment: I was looking for this Regex for my Levenshtain algorithm implementation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Note I have made an assumption that you are retrieving the full morse code message in one go and not one character at a time*

Focusing on this point:
"If there is one space that is the end of the letter. If there is 2 or more spaces in a row that is the end of the word."

Personally, I'd use the `split()` method on the String class. This will split up a String into a String[] and then you can do some checks on the individual Strings in the array. Splitting on a space character like this will give you a couple of behavioural advantages:

1. Any strings that represent characters will have no trailing or leading spaces on them
2. Any sequences of multiple spaces will result in empty strings in the returned String[].

For example, calling split(" ") on the string "A B  C" would give you a String[] containing {"A", "B", "", "C"}

Using this, I would first check if the empty string appeared at all. If this was the case, it implies that there were at least 2 space characters next to each other in the input morse code message. Then you can just ignore any empty strings that occur after the first one and it will cater for any number of sequential empty strings.

Without wanting to complete your assignment for you, here is some sample code:

```
public String decode(final String morseCode) {
    final StringBuilder decodedMessage = new StringBuilder();

    final String[] splitMorseCode = morseCode.split(" ");

    for (final String morseCharacter : splitMorseCode) {
        if( "".equals(morseCharacter) ) {
            /* We now know we had at least 2 spaces in sequence
             * So we check to see if we already added a space to spearate the 
             * resulting decoded words. If not, then we add one. */
            if ( !decodedMessage.toString().endsWith(" ") ) {
                decodedMessage.append(" ");
            }
            continue;
        }

        //Some code that decodes your morse code character.
    }

    return decodedMessage.toString();
}
```

I also wrote a quick test. In my example I made "--" convert to "M". Splitting the decodedMessage on the space character was a way of counting the individual words that had been decoded.

```
@Test
public void thatDecoderCanDecodeMultipleWordsSeparatedByMultipleSpaces() {
    final String decodedMessage = this.decoder.decode("-- --  -- --   -- --    -- --     -- --       -- --        -- --");

    assertThat(decodedMessage.split(" ").length, is(7));
    assertThat(decodedMessage, is("MM MM MM MM MM MM MM"));
}
```

Of course, if this is still not making sense, then reading the [APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) always helps

Answer (score 1):

To detect if a String has more than one space:

```
if (str.matches(".*  .*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.,

```
public class StringTester {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s="Hello  ";
        int count=0;
        char chr[]= s.toCharArray();
       for (char chr1:chr){
           if(chr1==' ')
                  count++;
       }
        if(count>=2)
            System.out.println(" I got more than 2 spaces")   ;
    }
```